# I am trying to run node.js, how do I resolve "Cannot find module" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I am trying to run node.js on OS X Terminal (10.6.8 if anyone cares) but whenever I type in:

```
node server.js
```

I receive this error message:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module  '/Work/Mass_Exchange/front_end_dev/MXWeb/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Anybody know what's causing it and how I can fix it?

Comment: my guess is that `'/Work/Mass_Exchange/front_end_dev/MXWeb/server.js'` doesn't exist .. as you haven't even **hinted** at your code, it's only a guess

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you are not in the same folder in the terminal, cause I wouldn't expect your code to call upon itself, but couldn't tell with not even a small code snippet.

Comment: The only code I've written is a bunch of HTML and CSS files. All I'm trying to do is get the node.js server running so that I can view them properly. In the past all I did was enter the `node server.js` command in Terminal and it would run. However, upon looking again, I'm not seeing a server.js file there. No idea what happened. I wonder if I actually used a different command, or if the file mysteriously disappeared?

Comment: Actually, I just found the directory that has the server.js file, and tried executing the `node server.js` command there. I then received the following error: https://pastebin.com/XRfxzjff

Comment: Ok, now this error actually makes perfect sense. In the code you must have somewhere a line saying `nconf=require("ncof")` which orders node to look in the folder node_modules at the same level as your script for the nconf package. At the same level there should be a package.json file. If the nfonf is in the dependencies in the package.json file, executing in the terminal `npm i` should install it along with any other dependency. If it isn't run `npm i nconf --save` to install and save it in the package.conf.

 I suggest you have a look at node require (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying I need to run `npm i nconf --save` which will automatically add the code i need to the package.json file, and then I should be able to run `node server.js` without any problem?

Comment: I just looked in the package.json file and I'm seeing this code here: https://pastebin.com/TQNixam7 It's pointing to a Github repo that has been deleted. Could this be part of what's causing the issue too?

Comment: I would suggest first running `npm i` cause that will install all required package described in package.json. if that doesn't solve it then run `npm i nconf --save` which will only save nconf, so if an error for another missing package comes up you should run `npm i packagename --save`

Comment: And here are the contents of the package.json file just in case: https://pastebin.com/sDZjse3Z

Comment: It actually worked. No package is missing, the error you have now is related to the actual code,  you just get an unhandled exception. Fyi, if you are trying to run a server in port 80 in Linux, as it seems, you need to run nudo in admin (sudo) mode cause in Unix ports less than 1024 are restricted. Or just go in the code and change 80 to something else, like 8000

Comment: For `npm i packagename --save` I have no idea which packagename to write

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156850/discussion-between-ariel-cotton-and-jason).

Comment: Okay, how do I switch to a different port, then? Not entirely sure how to do what you're suggesting, or what you're suggesting exactly.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I went into the server.js file and found the line of code that said `"port": 80` and switched it to say `"port": 8000` instead. Thank you!